# centos 7 make FFmpeg /libavutil/common.h:33:19: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory

Tags: centos7, android-ffmpeg

ndk build ffmpeg 3.4.2  configure success ,but when I make it .fatal error like this
 [image]
configure script is
[image]

I make it in `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`

similar, I make fdkaac fatal error  too like this
[image]

I don't know I what is the problem of system

Answer (score 0):

I think  you should change android ndk version

I use the ndk r16b   I get the problem also

so  I use the ndk r15c

I success

I holp this can help you

this is my .sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf android/arm
echo "stone"
NDK=/xxxxxxx/android-ndk-r15c
NDK_VERSION=android-14
ARCH=arm
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/$NDK_VERSION/arch-$ARCH
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
CROSS_COMPILE=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$CROSS_COMPILE \
--target-os=android \
--arch=$ARCH \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

make clean
make -j8
make install
}
build_one
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~